# Play a video without sound using an Intent with ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, video, android-intent, mute

So I have this very usual piece of code in my widget, which plays a video on click.

```
    Intent nextintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    nextintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    nextintent.setDataAndType(pathToVideo, "video/*");
    context.startActivity(nextintent);
```

I somewhere also have a property that says wether this video should be played with sound or muted.

Now, just how do I tell my intent to abide by that property ? None of the flags or action types (as far as I've seen) specify that. Any clues ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility I used :

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

Now I'm not sure it works for now, because I have other MediaPlayer problems and can't test it. Plus the volume probably won't be set back to its original level once the video is done playing (which is what I'd ideally want).

Comment: This did work as expected (I changed emulator and video playback was fine). So sound was indeed off for the video, but it had been made entirely off.

Comment: The question would be : when do I know that the intent is over ? Because then I can memorize the volume value and set it back to that afterwards.

Comment: I'm totally alone on this one.